# Index properly to data in 2D hash table

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, hashtable

So I have a hash table composed of a 2d array of linked lists. I have a compare function where I try to compare the contents of each linked list with the 8 cells that surround it. I tried to use the same logic that I would use for a 2d array of integers by making two for loops and toying with the increments. However after testing this I know I'm going about this wrong.This is just example code, I'm trying to figure out why I am not allowed to modify the grid location. temp2 segfaults.

```
Node* temp;
Node* temp2;
//grid is a filled 2d array of linked lists 
for(int j=0; j<b; j++)
{
    for(int i=0; i<b; i++)
    {
        //This works for ex printing out the entire grid
        temp = grid[j][i];
        while(temp != NULL)
        {

            cout << temp->xval;
            temp = temp->next;
        }   
        //However this is not allowed
        temp2 = grid[j+1][i]
        while(temp2 != NULL)
        {
            cout << temp2->xval;
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: If `j = b-1`, `grid[j+1][i]` is likely to be out of the bounds of your table.

Comment: This is what I figured thanks Franck. Im guessing adding a condition is the most elegant solution?

Comment: I don't understand the difference to a simple 2d array of integers. You have the same problem of special conditions at the boundaries there too, right?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely trying to access a 'cell' which does not exist when you do:

```
    temp2 = grid[j+1][i]
    while(temp2 != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp2->xval;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }
```

All you're doing is checking that the memory at `temp2` is not `null` but there is no guarantee it is null, part of your arrays or even assigned to your program.

The easiest way to fix this is to check that both `j` and `i` are always less than `b`.

EDIT:

The reason you haven't come across this when using integer arrays is just luck.

With an integer array you're still reading beyond the end of the array but you're interpreting whatever bytes you find as an integer. Most of the time you'll probably just be reading some other random variable in your program so no error occurs.

With your linked list you're interpreting what you find as a cell which contains a pointer. You are then dereferencing this gibberish pointer which means you're no longer accessing memory 'just after' the array but potentially somewhere 'far away'. This makes it much more likely you'll cause a segfault.